# How do I update "read" to true in all the children of messages in firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database structure]

My messages child has children with property read .I want to set it as true. How do I do that in javascript? (i want read property of all the children of messages set to true in a single command).
I tried `let ref =  yield firebase.database().ref(groups/${groupId}/messages).update({read:true})` but didn't work.
I also want to know if this is a good structure for the database

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to read the `messages` node to get all its children (with the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once) method) and then use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#update) method to update all the sub-nodes in one call.

The following code should do the trick:

```
        //set groupId value
        var db = firebase.database();
        db.ref(`groups/${groupId}/messages`)
        .once('value')
        .then(function (snapshot) {
              var updates = {};
              snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                  var key = childSnapshot.key;
                  updates[`groups/${groupId}/messages/${key}/read`] = true;
              });
              return db.ref().update(updates);
         });
```

See also https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

---

"I also want to know if this is a good structure for the database" -> This is quite a broad question which answer depends on many factors, including your User Requirements, the screens of your app, etc...

Comment: it worked! thank you! :) @RenaudTarnec